# seleccionar solo ciertas columnas mySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda sobre un ejercicio de SQL, el cual pide que seleccione solamente la primera, segunda y tercera **columna** de una tabla y el resultado debe aparecer ordenado descendentemente por la lista de selección.

Esto es fácil de realizar, pero pregunto si hay alguna manera dinámica de hacerlo.

Hasta ahora he realizado esto y funciona, pero claro si se añaden más columnas a la tabla tengo que modificar la consulta.

```
SELECT NumEmp , FNac, Ventas from empleado order by 3 desc;
```

Esta son las colúmnas de la tabla.

[image: iColumnas de la tabla Empleado.]
Gracias

Comment: No entiendo la utilidad de lo que quieres hacer, aún cuando agregues las nuevas columnas supongo que querrás seguir sacando la misma información. No le veo el sentido a esa practica, igualmente creo que usando SQL exclusivamente no vas a poder realizarlo.

Comment: Gracias @JoseAntonioLopezLopez simplemente es un ejercicio para practicar.

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que queres hacer dinamico...

Comment: Si se añaden más columnas a la tabla tu consulta seguirá funcionando con las tres columnas que pides mostrar. Ahora, si te piden que muestres una nueva columna, claro, deberás modificar tu consulta. Igual que Gonzalo no entiendo muy bien dónde buscas lo dinámico.

Comment: Si por dinámico entiendes que se muestren todas las columnas que existan en la tabla, entonces bastaría con un `SELECT * FROM ....` donde el `*` pide que se traigan todas las columnas de la tabla. Si no es eso, entonces, como dicen los compañeros, explica en qué consiste el dinamismo que deseas pulsando en  [edit]. Saludos.